# Store a CharFiled with a value, how can I get another value when read it?

Tags: django, django-models

The CharFiled saved with a value, but I want to make some modifications with the stored value when reading it, but the value in db doesn't change. How should I do ?
my code as follows:

```
class TFile(models.Model):
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=LANGUAGE.choices())
    domain = models.ForeignKey(TDomain, null=True, verbose_name="领域", related_name="domain", on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=FILETYPE.choices())
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    path = PathFiled(max_length=1000)
```

eg: I set path a value as "/home/work/workspace", but I want to read it out as "/workspace", What should I do, or What function should I override in my custom filed PathField.

Comment: `@property` simple way but you should add more details and show code.

Comment: I add some details, please review this question again.

Answer (score 0):

As Bear mentioned in a comment, Let's say I have a model called Menu with two fields and property I can define in the class to represent modified version of db value.

```
class Menu(models.Model):

    identifier = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("identifier"), max_length=100)
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.PROTECT)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.identifier

    @property
    def root_id(self)
        # Do whatever modification you would like here... for example
        # below I prefix "root-" to an identifier
        return "root-" + self.identifier
```

Comment: I add some details, please review this question again.

Comment: @XiaolinWu what do you want else from the answer?

Comment: as the example mentioned, I want to mentioned path as path again, only changed its  value when I read it .

Comment: path you can use as obj.path and use new attribute as property